# Specified cast not valid calling stored procedure

Tags: sql, linq, ssis

I am confronted with this devilish error : "Specified cast not valid" ; while calling a stored procedure through Linq.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @packagename VARCHAR(100)
declare @servername VARCHAR(100)
SET @packagename = 'PackageName'
SET @servername = 'servername'
DECLARE @ssisstr varchar(8000) 

set @ssisstr = 'C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SQL Server"\100\DTS\Binn\dtexec /sql ' + @packagename + ' /ser ' + @servername + ' ';

----now execute dynamic SQL by using EXEC. 

declare @returncode nvarchar(100)

EXEC @returncode = xp_cmdshell @ssisstr;

select @returncode
```

The return looks like like a table with one column and content:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.4260.0 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
NULL
...
```

stored procedure call looks like

```
using (DataContext context = new DataContext (connection))
{
       var returncode = context.StoredProcedure(packagname,servername);
}
```

Comment: Does the stored procedure work if invoked directly? I assume there's a reason you're using a script task when you could have used the Script Task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Stored procedures return a status value, which is always an integer.  So, the statements:

```
declare @returncode nvarchar(100)
EXEC @returncode = xp_cmdshell @ssisstr;
```

are highly suspect.  This may fix your error:

```
declare @returncode int;
EXEC @returncode = xp_cmdshell @ssisstr;
```

However, I'm guessing this will not be doing what you really want.  If not, ask another question and describe what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Integer return type is an acceptable solution. The code was also lacking the following no_output parameter:

```
DECLARE @returncode int
EXEC @returncode = xp_cmdshell @ssisstr, no_output;
select @returncode
```

Works, thanks!